# Primes of index at most the Minkowski constant invertible implies all primes invertible

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise and I am looking for a **hint** into the right direction.

> Let $R$ be an order in a number field $K$. Show that we have $R=\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if all primes $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R$ of index at most the Minkowski constant $M_R$ of $R$ are invertible.

A prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ is invertible if and only if $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a DVR. Moreover, we know that $R=\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if *all* primes of $R$ are invertible.

We know that the Picard group of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is generated by all primes of $\mathcal{O}_K$ of index at most the Minkowski constant $M_K\leq M_R$.

I thought of using the surjection $\operatorname{Pic} R\to \operatorname{Pic} \mathcal{O}_K,I\mapsto I\mathcal{O}_K$, however a prime which is not invertible does not lie in the Picard group, which consists of the *invertible* ideals modulo the principal ideals.

Any ideas ?